# Adding info to table with stringbuilder and then sorting C# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist, html-table

I am kind of new to C# and ASP.Net

I want to make a web app where I can add information to a html table to be shown.
Nothing really advanced with MySQL and things like that, just a simple one.

I want to make it possible to add the persons and then later on sort them by their gender (Male, Female), but whatever I try, the list to show them all works, but the 2 other doesn't.
When I add a male, I can see the male, but if I add a female, the male disappears and there comes a female in the other table. And so on..

Here is a gif of what it is doing:

[image: Gif of problem]

I have tried to make it this way:

**WebForm1.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int pressAddButton1;
    int pressAddButton2;
    int pressAddButton3;

    Label information1 = new Label();
    Label information2 = new Label();
    Label information3 = new Label();

    static StringBuilder newInfo1 = new StringBuilder();
    static StringBuilder newInfo2 = new StringBuilder();
    static StringBuilder newInfo3 = new StringBuilder();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
        public class Person {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Gender { get; set; }
            public string Mnr { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }

            public Person(string name, string gender, string mnr, string password)
            {
                Name = name;
                Gender = gender;
                Mnr = mnr;
                Password = password;
            }
        }

        protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Person PersonID = new Person(name.Text, gender.Text, mnr.Text, password.Text);

            pressAddButton1++;
            if (gender.Text == "Male")
            {
                pressAddButton2++;
            }

            if (gender.Text == "Female")
            {
                pressAddButton3++;
            }

            information1.ID = "information1" + pressAddButton1;
            if (gender.Text == "Male")
            {
                information2.ID = "information2" + pressAddButton2;
            }

            if (gender.Text == "Female")
            {
                information3.ID = "information3" + pressAddButton3;
            }

            newInfo1.Append(string.Format(@"<tr><td>" + name.Text + "</td><td>" + gender.Text + "</td><td>" + mnr.Text + "</td><td>" + password.Text + "</td></tr>"));

                if (gender.Text == "Male")
                    {
                        newInfo2.Append(string.Format(@"<tr><td>" + name.Text + "</td><td>" + gender.Text + "</td><td>" + mnr.Text + "</td><td>" + password.Text + "</td></tr>"));
                    }

                if (gender.Text == "Female")
                    {
                        newInfo3.Append(string.Format(@"<tr><td>" + name.Text + "</td><td>" + gender.Text + "</td><td>" + mnr.Text + "</td><td>" + password.Text + "</td></tr>"));
                    }

            information1.Text += newInfo1.ToString();

                if (gender.Text == "Male")
                    {
                        information2.Text += newInfo2.ToString();
                    }

                if (gender.Text == "Female")
                    {
                        information3.Text += newInfo3.ToString();
                    }

            Panel1.Controls.Add(information1);

                if (gender.Text == "Male")
                    {
                        Panel2.Controls.Add(information2);
                    }

                if (gender.Text == "Female")
                    {
                        Panel3.Controls.Add(information3);
                    }

            name.Text = "";
            mnr.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

**WebForm1.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Person ToString</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px; border-radius: 5px; width: 323px;">
    <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" Width="320px" placeholder="Name.."></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="gender" runat="server" Width="324px">
        <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="mnr" runat="server" Width="320px" placeholder="Member Number.."></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="320px" placeholder="Password.."></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="add" runat="server" OnClick="add_Click" Text="Add" Width="324px" />
</div>
    <br />
    All:<br />
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Gender</td>
            <td>Member Number</td>
            <td>Password</td>
        </tr>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    </table>
    <br />
    Male:
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Gender</td>
            <td>Member Number</td>
            <td>Password</td>
        </tr>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    </table>
    <br />
    Female:
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Gender</td>
            <td>Member Number</td>
            <td>Password</td>
        </tr>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have heard that maybe it would be easier to use Arraylist and GridView or something, but I don't know how to do it.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I created. Hope it helps. You can download it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2B-TE1F6K1ZRnctYnhScTh0bjA/view?usp=sharing).

It uses a GridView control that is sortable (click on the header text) and a SqlDataSource for data access.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 50px">
    <div class="col-lg-8">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">All Users</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CssClass="table" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="MemberNumber" HeaderText="MemberNumber" SortExpression="MemberNumber" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="Password" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [User]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Male Users</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" CssClass="table" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="MemberNumber" HeaderText="MemberNumber" SortExpression="MemberNumber" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="Password" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE ([Gender] = @Gender)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Male" Name="Gender" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Female Users</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" CssClass="table" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="MemberNumber" HeaderText="MemberNumber" SortExpression="MemberNumber" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="Password" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE ([Gender] = @Gender)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Female" Name="Gender" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Add User</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text="Name" AssociatedControlID="NameTextBox"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Gender" AssociatedControlID="GenderDropDownList"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="GenderDropDownList" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control">
                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Male" Value="Male"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="Female"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Member Number" AssociatedControlID="MemberNumberTextBox"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="MemberNumberTextBox" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Password" AssociatedControlID="PasswordTextBox"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="PasswordTextBox" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="AddButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary form-control" OnClick="AddButton_Click">Add User</asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using a nuget package called NPoco to simplify the database insert...

```
protected void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Insert new user
    using (var db = new Database("DatabaseConnectionString"))
    {
        db.Insert("User", "Id", true,
            new
            {
                Name = NameTextBox.Text,
                Gender = GenderDropDownList.SelectedValue,
                MemberNumber = MemberNumberTextBox.Text,
                Password = PasswordTextBox.Text
            });
    }

    // Refresh the data in the grid
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView2.DataBind();
    GridView3.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but I got a new problem now. It somehow seems that i can't connect to the SQL server.

I says:

    
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

And then

    [SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "Database1_1" requested by the login. The login failed.
    Login failed for user 'ISMAIL-PC\imano_000'.]

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention you in the comment.